# Border not showing under <tr> element in a HTML table

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add border at bottom side of my table header.
but is is not showing without any error.
I can see it is ok when I inspect elements.

Here is my code:

```
.cart_table{
width:100%;} 

.cart_table_header{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ffb215;
padding: 8px;
background-color: #dedede;}
.cart_table tr td{
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

Here is Html

```
        <table class="cart_table" >
        <tr class="cart_table_header">
            <th> </th>
            <th> Item </th>
            <th> Price </th>
            <th> Quantity </th>
            <th> Total  </th>
            <th> Remove </th>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td> <img src="images/product-image.jpg" height="50px width:50px;"> </img> </td>
            <td> Item name here</td>
            <td> $12</td>
            <td> 2</td>
            <td> $24</td>
            <td> <a href="#"> <img src="images/delete_icon_normal.png" > </img> </a> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr valign="middle">
            <td> <img src="images/product-image.jpg" height="50px width:50px;"> </img> </td>
            <td> Item name here</td>
            <td> $12</td>
            <td> 2</td>
            <td> $24</td>
            <td> <a href="#"> <img src="images/delete_icon_normal.png" > </img> </a> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `border-collapse:collapse;` to your table rules:

```
.cart_table {
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qxtkmd8w/)**

Answer (score 1):

tr elements can't display border by themselves, but you can add it to the th elements

```
.cart_table_header th {
    border-bottom:1px solid black;
}
```

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amenadiel/cfd8p2Lg/)

If you want the border to look like a continuous line, you can add `border-collapse:collapse;` to the table class as @j08691 said.

Comment: this is not i want but thanks. i want without break point

Comment: Yup, I got that when I saw the accepted answer. Worth the shot anyway :)